# How to collect all possible contiguous sequences of words from a string?

Tags: javascript

For example, if space is a separator and

```
var str = "ab cde fgh ij klmn opq";
```

I want to get

```
var result = [
["ab", "cde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn", "opq"],
["ab", "cde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn opq"],
["ab", "cde", "fgh", "ij klmn opq"],
//...
["ab", "cde", "fgh ij", "klmn opq"],
["ab", "cde", "fgh ij klmn", "opq"],
//...
["ab cde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn", "opq"],
["ab cde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn opq"],
//...
["ab cde", "fgh ij", "klmn opq"],
["ab cde", "fgh ij klmn", "opq"],
//...
["ab cde fgh ij klmn", "opq"]
];
```

What is an efficient way of solving such a problem?

My own attempt solved only a part of the problem:

1. remove `"ab"`, and then get 
   `"ab" + ["cde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn", "opq"], ["cde", "fgh", "ij", "klmn opq"]`...
2. remove `"ab cde"`, and then get 
   `"ab cde" + ["fgh", "ij", "klmn", "opq"], ["fgh", "ij", "klmn opq"]`...

...and so on. But this approach will not allow to collect **all possible** sequences (as seen in the above example).

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: the `"ab cde fgh", ...` sequence is missed, why?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: There are `//...` comments in the code, I assumed that they should denote all missing sequences

Comment: @lyricallywicked, ok, have you tried `forEach` and `slice` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your sequences recursively. Just join first word to each sequence build from rest or append it as new word. Although there is a little of problem with call stack overflow with this solution.

But you can see basic idea.

```js
const str = 'ab cde fgh ij';

function getAllSequences(words) {
  if (words.length === 1) {
    return [words];
  }
  
  const [first, ...rest] = words;
  const sequences = getAllSequences(rest);
  
  return sequences.reduce((sequences, sequence) => {
    const withFirstConnected = [].concat(first + ' ' + sequence[0], sequence.slice(1));
    const withFirstUnshift = [].concat(first, sequence);
    
    return sequences.concat([withFirstConnected], [withFirstUnshift]);
  }, []);
}

console.log(getAllSequences(str.split(' ')));
```

Another version without recursion, similar approach but with adding last word instead of first.

```js
function getAllSequences(words) {
  return words.reduce(addWordToSequences, [[]]);
}

function addWordToSequences(sequences, word) {
  return sequences.reduce((sequences, sequence) => {
    if (sequence.length === 0) {
      return [[word]];
    }
    
    const last = sequence[sequence.length - 1];
    const front = sequence.slice(0, sequence.length - 1);
    const withWordJoined = front.concat(last + ' ' + word);

    return sequences.concat([withWordJoined], [sequence.concat(word)]);
  }, []);
}

console.log(getAllSequences('something mdd ala ba'.split(' ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an abstraction of the problem and try to distribute just the sum of all items and use a for loop for it with a recusion of the already distributed parts.

```js
function combine(array) {

    function c(l, r) {
        var i, p = 0;

        if (l === 0) {
            result.push(r.map(function (a) {
                p += a;
                return array.slice(p - a, p);
            }));
            return;
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
            c(l - i, r.concat(i));
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    c(array.length, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(combine("ab cde fgh ij klmn opq".split(' ')));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the set of words, like this:

```
var setOfWords = str.split(" ");
```

Then, you need to get all the combinations you need, like this:

```
function generateCombinations(setOfWords) {
    var lastIndex = setOfWords.length - 1;
    var firstIndex = setOfWords.length - 1;
    while (lastIndex >= 0) {
        while (firstIndex >= 0) {
            var combination = [];
            for (var index = firstIndex; index <= lastIndex; index++) {
                combination.push(setOfWords);
            }
            var result = combination.join(" ");
            //Do something with result, as it is a valid output
            firstIndex--;
        }
        lastIndex--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be really easy for you to understand if you try to think of your array of continuous string as an array of continuous numbers:

Think of your array of continuous strings as equivalent to this

```
[ab, cde, fgh, ij, klmn, opq] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Assuming this makes it far easy to approach our problem.

Initial Sequence:[1,2,3,4,5,6] -  Seq - 1

Now, you need to understand that, here a continues would be only formed if you concat their just next ones(string or number) or there combinations.

Example : In Initial sequence, 5 can go with 6 as 6 is the immediate(continuous) next to 5, but 4 cannot got with 6, similarly 4 can go with combination 56(continuouos combination).  All we need to do is, to make sure that these combinations are continuous and immediate to 4.

First what we'll do is will make few continuous sequence form initial seq, each output sequence is an input to arrive to another continuous sequence.

Example:

Sequence obtained by concating their immediate next ones.

```
[1,2,3,4,56]  -  Seq  - 2
[1,2,3,45,6]  -  Seq  - 3
[1,2,34,5,6]  -  Seq  - 4
[1,23,4,5,6]  -  Seq  - 5
[12,3,4,5,6]  -  Seq  - 6
```

Same we need to evaluate for seq-2 to seq-6.

Example:

Seq-2 would result into:

```
Input->   
 [1,2,3,4,56]  -  Seq  - 2
Sequence obtained by concating their immediate next ones. 

Output->
    [1,2,3,4,56]  -  Seq  - 7
    [1,2,3,456]  -  Seq  - 8
    [1,2,34,56]  -  Seq  - 9
    [1,23,4,56]  -  Seq  - 10
    [12,3,4,56]  -  Seq  - 11
```

Now, again seq-7 to seq-11 is a new set of input sequesces, just like sequence seq2-seq6, and same contatenation needs to be carried out for all these sequences.

Now, according to me there are two possible approaches to acheive this:
1. Recursion
2. Stack

While, I'm not going to code it for you, I'll give you a brief about the second approach.

```
Step:1. Initailly your stack in empty.
Step:2  With each input sequence you will obtain some output sequences.
Step:3  Push these output sequences back in the stack.
Step:4  Pop the top of the stack and store it in an temp array and push the outputs back to the stack.
Step:5 Temp array will store all the sequences.
```

Abviously, you need to provide some condition check to avoid pushing a repetitive sequence twice. 
I hope that make sense.

Also, I would suggest you to add the algorithm tag, I'll gain you far better answers. It is more of a algorithm question than a javascript question.

Comment: I was going to add the "algorithm" tag before asking this question, but was afraid that it would be better to pick only one of two tags: 1. javascript; 2. algorithm. Is it appropriate to ask about an algorithm and its implementation in the specific language - all in one question?

Comment: I won't suggest asking in any specific language, It's more about the general idea of how to approach the problem. Once that is understood the rest is easy. Algorithm is language independent.